# How to Create an Array in Decimal Hours from Python Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file called One_Orbit and am trying to create a time array in decimal hours. I used pandas read_table to open the file and create longitude and latitude arrays which work great. I am stuck trying to make a time array now. I tried to convert to integers to be able to do math with the Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and Milliseconds in the text file. These are the first few lines in the text file for reference:

```
Year    Month   Day Hour    Minute  Second  Millisecond Longitude   Latitude    Altitude
2019    3   17  5   55  55  0   108.8730074 50.22483151 412.6226898
2019    3   17  5   56  0   0   108.9895097 50.53642185 412.7368197
2019    3   17  5   56  5   0   109.1078294 50.8478274  412.850563
2019    3   17  5   56  10  0   109.2280101 51.15904424 412.9640113
2019    3   17  5   56  15  0   109.3500969 51.47006828 413.0772319
```

However, I am getting stuck with the error 'unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'' and I'm not sure how to fix it to create a time array in decimal hours from the data frame I already have. This is my code and the error is coming from the last line beginning with time.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('One_Orbit.txt', sep=r'\s+')

long = df['Longitude']
lat = df['Latitude']

df['Hour'].astype(int)
df['Minute'].astype(int)
df['Second'].astype(int)
df['Millisecond'].astype(int)


time = df['Hour' + 'Minute'/60 + 'Second'/3600 + 'Millisecond'/3600000]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Are you familiar with the basics of Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in that the line `time = df['Hour' + 'Minute'/60 + 'Second'/3600 + 'Millisecond'/3600000]`, python is trying to parse `'Hour' + 'Minute'/60 + 'Second'/3600 + 'Millisecond'/3600000` and is in turn trying to do `'Minute'/60`. *This* is where the error is coming from

Simply change your last line to

`time = df['Hour'] + df['Minute']/60 + df['Second']/3600 + df['Millisecond']/3600000`

Now, the values from the `Minute` column get divided by 60 and then added to the values from the `Hour` column

For me, this output the following pandas Series

```
time
0    5.931944
1    5.933333
2    5.934722
3    5.936111
4    5.937500
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to

```
time = df['Hour'] + df['Minute']/60 + df['Second']/3600 + df['Millisecond']/3600000
```

Output:

```
0    5.931944
1    5.933333
2    5.934722
3    5.936111
4    5.937500
dtype: float64
```